# Question about the h-principle

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, smooth-manifolds, h-principle

So generally we define a differential relation to be $\mathcal{R} \subset X^{(r)}.$ In the case that $X=M\times N$ is it possible to have $\mathcal{R}=X^{(1)}$? So in this case the formal solutions would be (my guess) just fiberwise linear bundle maps that covers a continuous map and the genuine (holonomic) solutions would be bundle maps that are the derivative of a  smooth map $f: M \to N$. In none of the books (Gromov, Eliashberg & Mishachev) i have seen they treat this case. Does this mean that the case $\mathcal{R}=X^{(1)}$ cannot be treated and what i said before is plainly wrong? On the other case, if something can be said, under what conditions the *h*-principle (lets say surjectiveness of $\pi_0$ ) holds?

Comment: You question is not readable!

Comment: What do you mean exactly by " not readable" ?

Comment: I think you could improve it by defining your notation. I'm not an expert in the area and I'm sure it is defined in the references you provided, still it could be helpful to provide a quick reference. (For example: what is $X$? A manifold? A space? Something weirder? What does $X^{(r)}$ means?)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to have $\mathcal{R}=X^{(1)}$, i.e. to have a system of partial differential equations that consists of no equations at all. Then as you say the formal solutions are sections of $X^{(1)} \to M$, while the holonomic solutions are sections of $X \to M$. The surjectivity is obvious, since the fibers of $X^{(1)} \to X$ are affine spaces (which Gromov points out, but you can check as an exercise), so contractible, so $\pi_0$ is onto, i.e. if you have no differential equations to solve then nothing interesting in PDE happens.

To explain the notation, $p \colon X \to M$ is a fiber bundle (or maybe something more general, but this is good enough) and $X^{(1)}$ is the set of pairs $(m,x,u)$ so that $m \in M$, $x \in X_m$, $u \colon T_m M \to T_x X$ is a linear map so that $p'(x) \circ u \colon T_m M \to T_m M$ is the identity linear map. Every section $s \colon M \to X$ gives a section $s' \colon M \to X^{(1)}$ by differentiating. A section $M \to X^{(1)}$ is holonomic if it is $s'$ for some $s$.

Comment: yes thanks for clarifying that out. This came to me while i was reading Sharpe's book of Differential Geometry in the proof of "Fundamental Theorem of calculus, Global version th. 7.14 which seems to me it has an h-principle underlying (albeit not very sophisticated if at all) but i could be completely wrong, so my motivation was to maybe write a proof with these method